# delete an object from git by hash

Tags: git

Say I do `echo hello | git hash-object --stdin -w`. Now I've got this object in the working area.

I know I can go to `.git/objects` folder, find the object and simply delete it. I also can do `git prune`, which I am a little scared of.

Is there any way through git command to delete a single object by hash?. Something like:

```
$ echo hello | git hash-object --stdin -w
ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a
$ git remove-object-by-hash ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a    # <- something like this
```

Comment: git is not designed to remove anything from the database, at least manually. removing it as you suggest will just corrupt it.

Comment: @matt ok. will note it.

Comment: @Serge why would it get corrupt? I am just removing an object not attached to any other object.

Comment: The blob object holding the content `hello` (and a newline) might be in use: if any of your committed or in-progress files contain, as their content, that single line, *those* commits (or your index) will use that hash ID.

Answer (score 3):

No, Git doesn't provide this functionality.  While it shouldn't cause any problems to delete an object which isn't in use, it isn't trivial to determine which objects are in use by some part of the history or reflogs, and deleting one of those objects would cause your repository to be corrupt.

Git expects that you will create objects that end up not being used, and these are cleaned up periodically by `git gc` if they're no longer used by anything.  This calls `git prune` to do the actual cleanup, as you've noted.  This ensures that only unused objects are destroyed and that the repository remains intact after pruning.